# unity web player download prompt

Tags: web, unity-game-engine

My website has a web player in it called Unity Web Player. I am working on a page that checks to see if the user has the unity web player installed. If the user already has the web player the user goes directly from the loading screen to the website. If the user does not have unity web player, the user is directed to the page I am working on. Here, the user is prompted to download the Unity Web Player. Please help, this is so important to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HTMLcodetoloadUnityWebPlayercontent.html)...